# Can I write a kernel module to handle a software interrupt?

Tags: linux, driver, device, interrupt

I was just learning about interrupt handling in linux kernel modules and i was wondering if i can request_irq() for a vector say 0xF0 and enter the handler from a user space program that executes int 0xF0 instruction. I'm just wondering if i can register interrupt handlers for software interrupts as well.

Comment: What research have you done so far?  Have you been unable to find the answer to this question in Google?

Comment: yes. I have tried to google it. i did not find much in the way of doing this. found a couple of questions on stack overflow but nothing that explicitly says this can or cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot write a kernel module to handle software interrupts. All software interrupts on x86_64 are between 0x1F & 0xFF. These are marked as special interrupts and register_irq() will never succeed.